# Terraform instance group doesn't select any health check even though it has defined in auto_healing_policies

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm creating GCP instance groups through Terraform. First I create the health check with following:

```
resource "google_compute_health_check" "http_8080" {
  name                = "http-8080"
  check_interval_sec  = 10
  timeout_sec         = 10
  healthy_threshold   = 3
  unhealthy_threshold = 10                         # 50 seconds

  http_health_check {
    request_path = "/"
    port         = "8080"
  }
}
```

After that I have my instance group code, where I define "auto_healing_policies" and attached to that I have my health check:

```
resource "google_compute_instance_group_manager" "app_instance_group" {
  name = "app-instance-group"

  base_instance_name = "app-node"
  instance_template  = "${google_compute_instance_template.app_template.self_link}"
  update_strategy    = "NONE"
  zone               = "${var.current_zone}"

  target_size  = 0

  named_port {
    name = "app8080"
    port = 8080
  }

    auto_healing_policies {
    health_check      = "${google_compute_health_check.http_8080.self_link}"
    initial_delay_sec = 300
  }
}
```

terraform validate : success

terraform plan:

I can see following;

```
      + auto_healing_policies {
          + health_check      = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/deltadna-live/global/healthChecks/http-8080"
          + initial_delay_sec = 300
        }


terraform apply : Apply complete!
```

But when I go to instance group and check if everything is correct, health check is set to "**No health check**", but my health check is created just fine.

I am trying to understand why instance group doesn't apply my health check.

Thanks,.